# Unity 8 Gets Stuck at Login Screen

Tags: 16.04, login, login-screen, lts, unity8

Today I just did a fresh install of the latest Ubuntu LTS edition. I have been wanting to test Unity 8 for a long time but I never had the time to do it. Today when I finally did try it out I discovered that I could not even start Unity 8. I installed Unity 8 from the command `sudo apt install unity8-desktop-session-mir` but when I went to log in it wouldn't work. As soon as I enter my password the dots over the background disappear and so does the password box. I have waited for about ten minutes but it still won't log in. I can move my mouse still and click the buttons on the top menu bar though. If I press ESC on my keyboard the password box will reappear and I can change the desktop session back to Unity 7 and log into that. I even went as far as to do another fresh install of Ubuntu in the same day and do everything over again but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried installing unity through `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: That's for Unity 7 though right?

Comment: Unity 7 works just fine. It's Unity 8 that doesn't start.

Comment: Not 100% sure. I was just wondering if you tried it. And oh

Comment: No. I just did a feesh install of Ubuntu and then installed Unity 8.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure. I found a similar post and it said to run `unity8 -mousetouch` in the terminal to start it.

Comment: `unity8 -mousetouch
Mode argument was not provided or was set to an illegal value. Using default value of --mode= "full-greeter"
file:///usr/share/unity8//OrientedShell.qml:232:5: Type Shell unavailable 
         Shell { 
         ^
file:///usr/share/unity8//Shell.qml:20:1: plugin cannot be loaded for module "Unity.Application": Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/Unity/Application/libunityapplicationplugin.so: (libqpa-mirserver.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) 
     import Unity.Application 0.1 
     ^
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`